# Show a function is in $L_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f\colon [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is measurable, and suppose there exists $M>0$ s.t. $\forall h\in\mathbb L_2[0,\infty)$ We have $ |\int _{[0,\infty)}f(x)h(x)d\mu (x)|\leq M\cdot \|h\| _
{L_2}$. 
Show that $f\in L_2$.

I got stuck at the end (My attempt is at the bottom). I would love to hear some suggestions on how to tackle this 1.

My Attempt: 
I started noticing $h\mapsto \int _{[0,\infty)}hf$ is bounded functional, and so there exists (By Riesz representation theorem) $g\in L_2$ such that $\langle h,g \rangle =\int_{[0,\infty)}h\bar g= \int _{[0,\infty)}hf$.
 Now we have $\forall h \in L_2 \ .\ \int_{[0,\infty)}h(f-\bar g) = 0$ Next we define a series of functions: $$ s_n =  \begin{cases}
    \mathrm{sign}(f-\bar g) & {{x\in[0,n]}} \\
    0 & \text{O.W.}
  \end{cases}$$
Obviously $s_n \in L_2[0,\infty)$ And $\int_{[0,\infty)}s_n\cdot(f-\bar g) = 0$. We now notice some facts:
$$r_n = s_n \cdot (f-\bar g) =  \begin{cases}
    |f-\bar g| & {{x\in[0,n]}} \\
    0 & \text{O.W.}
  \end{cases}$$ $r_n \in L_2[0,\infty)$ and $0\leq r_1 \leq r_2 \leq \dots$

Now, if i could only show $r_n \rightarrow |f-\bar g|$ Then i could switch the order of integration and say that $f-\bar g \overset{\text{a.e.}}{=}0$ And finally: $f\in L_2[0,\infty)$

Edit: After reviewing this, is it really that obvious that $r_n \xrightarrow{\text{a.e.}} |f-\bar g| $? (It seems too obvious to be true..eh).

Comment: You made a mistake : in $r_n$ it is not $|f-\bar{g}|^2$ but $|f-\bar{g}|$

Comment: @stity Yes you are right, i corrected this.

Comment: Even if $\int_0^\infty |f-\bar{g}| = 0$ it does not imply that $f=\bar{g}$ because you do not know if $|f-\bar{g}|$ is continous

Comment: @stity In $L_2$ It indeed implies $f\overset{\text{a.e}}{=} \bar g$

Comment: Does $a.e.$ stand for "almost everywhere" ? In this case, my bad I did not knew this notation

Comment: @stity Yes this is how I use this 1 (After seeing it in lectures). Honestly I don't know if this is widely used..

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in [0,\infty)$. For $n \ge x$, we have that
$$ r_n(x) = |f-\bar g|(x) $$
hence $\bigl(r_n(x)\bigr)$ is finally constant and converges to $|f-\bar g|(x)$. So $r_n \to |f-\bar g|$ (at every $x$).